# Connection dropping after upgrade to Sierra

Tags: network, macos, upgrade, ping

We have a Mac mini which we use for remote building some iOS applications written on Xamarin. All build scripts are executed via SSH. Recently we have upgraded its OS from El Capitan to Sierra, but after it we encountered with a problem that Mac ocassionaly becomes unpingable at all. Its network connection is unstable and sometimes it work works quite well, but other times when we try to ping Mac, it throws next:

```
Pinging <MacMini_ip> with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Reply from <MacMini_ip>: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=32

...

Reply from <my_ip>: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from <my_ip>: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from <my_ip>: Destination host unreachable.
```

We thought that there are problems with network cable or switch, but after replacing the problem still occurs. Can anyone answer why does this happen? Are there any problems with Mac settings? I have quite few experience in working with Mac.